# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, orm

I am trying to configure hibernate orm mapping tool to my java class and using PostgreSQL as my database and configured the password as "password". When I tried to run the application, I have encountered error on my console logs as
**Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]**.
I have tried this on old version of hibernate and it worked. The hibernate version that I am using right now is version 5.1.0.

The following is the error log:

```
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:09 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 31, 2016 3:55:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.javabrains.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sa"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:208)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
```

The following is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        
        
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    
    <!-- Names the annotated entity class-->
    <mapping class="org.javabrains.dto.UserDetails"/>
    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My POJO class

```
package org.javabrains.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
}
```

And my application class:

```
package org.javabrains.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.javabrains.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Tet");
        
        //Hibernate API to save this objects to DB
        //Session factory is created only ONCE
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        //create transaction
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        
        //end the transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
        //Closing the session
        session.close();
        
        
    }

}
```

The following is the image of java hibernate structure

[image]

Answer (score 68):

*Cause:* The error occurred since hibernate is not able to connect to the database.
*Solution:*
 
1. Please ensure that you have a database present at the server referred to in the configuration file eg. "hibernatedb" in this case.
2. Please see if the username and password for connecting to the db are correct.
3. Check if relevant jars required for the connection are mapped to the project.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I found that the wrong database url (host, name..) has caused this exception to me.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need `hibernate-entitymanager-xxx.jar`, because of you use a Hibernate session approach (not `JPA`). You need to close the `SessionFactory` too and rollback a transaction on errors. But, the problem, of course, is not with those.

This is returned by a database

```
#
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sa"
#
```

Looks like you've provided an incorrect username or (and) password.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the right answer. This is the only reason where either of the user or password credentials are wrong. Thumbs up for the answer ..

Comment: @NagaVemprala Thank you :)

Comment: In my case I missed user name and got this error. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Either you experienced database connection issue or you missed any of the hibernate configurations to connect to database such as database DIALECT.

Happens if your database server was disconnected due to network related issue.

If you're using spring boot along with hibernate connected to Oracle Db, use

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com
```

Comment: Upvoted, I missed out the dialect setting which solved my issue with SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Check1: Remove line space from the application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatechie
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=9191
```

Check2: Or make sure @Id annotation is in POJO(entity) class.

Check3: verify username and password and privileges on the database. MySQL version is 8.0.31.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade MySql driver to **[Connector/Python 8.0.17](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)** or greater than 8.0.17, Those who are using greater than **MySQL 5.5 version**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the provided username had no privileges on database. Granting privileges resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse mars, Hibernate 5.2.1, Jdk7 and Oracle 11g.

I get the same error when I run Hibernate code generation tool. I guess it is a versions issue due to I have solved it through choosing Hibernate version (5.1 to 5.0) in the type frame in my Hibernate console configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the @ID above the userId

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and changing the following

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory =
    new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

to this

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory =
    new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

worked for me.

Comment: `configure(...)` has many types of parameters (File ,URL,Path) ,so it is not necessary to fix the location hibernate.cfg.xml ,and he did not menthioned the hibernate.cfg.xml file location.

Comment: I would give a Negative 100 for this answer

Answer (score 0):

you must stop another running app involved with especial database table ...
like running java API in other module or other project is not terminated .. so terminate running.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with MySQL as my database and the only solution was reinstall all components of MySQL, because before I installed just the server.

So try to download other versions of PostgreSQL and get all the components

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: the mistake I was making was having a double line defined between the properties. So you have to be very careful that the main connection properties are correct.

Secondly, make sure that the specified dialect is correct for the DB version you are using. To see the various dialects you need to go to the hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar file and from there look for the org.hybernate.dialect package which lists the various dialects available.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!-- property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <!--<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>-->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="org.test.connection.UserDetails" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also get "Unable to create requested service" when you (try to) use a JDBC driver that isn't installed.

Going by your stacktrace, I don't think that's the reason in your case - I just wanted to add it to the discussion for those who come here from searching for that error message.