# trying to connect to mysql database using eclipse and hibernate 5

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to connect to mysql using hibernate 5 and i'm getting this error on console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.moath.hibernate.HibernateMainTest.main(HibernateMainTest.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection ["jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moathdb"] at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:40) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:19) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74) at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
```

I've tried all stackoverflow questions related to this but can't solve it.

This is the entity class :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "user_details")
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int userId;
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

}
```

and this is the main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
    userDetails.setUserId(1);
    userDetails.setUserName("First User");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 
    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(userDetails);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

This is the hibernate configuration file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property 
name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property 
name="hibernate.connection.url">"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moathdb" 
</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property  name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

</session-factory>
```

I've checked the database username and password and all thing correct but i'm still getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345377/unable-to-create-requested-service-org-hibernate-engine-jdbc-env-spi-jdbcenviro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if you are using  Mysql 5.x

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

as dialect.

and / or

```
 <property 
name="hibernate.connection.url">"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moathdb" >
```

remove Quotes here.

your string look like below:

```
property 
name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moathdb>
```

it will work.

Comment: try by removing quotes into your db url string.

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing quotes in hibernate.connection.url value.