# Why Cannot i connect spring-boot container to mysql sql container by Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can i connect mysql container with spring-boot app container. I try use network then i try docker-compose but it seems my spring-boot app can't connect.

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
mysql-docker-container:
image: mysql:latest
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_app
volumes: 
  - /data/mysql
authenticate:
image: authenticate
build: 
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
depends_on:
  - mysql-docker-container
ports: 
  - "8080:8080"
volumes: 
  - /data/authentica
```

> application.properties

```
#cấu hình Spring Datasource, JPA, App Properties
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://my-docker-container:3306/my_app?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate,dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
#App 
pin.app.jwtSecret = pinSecretKey
pin.app.jwtExpirationMs = 86400000
```

[This's my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGvT.jpg)

Then i fix it by a network in compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_app
    volumes: 
      - /data/mysql
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - "my-network"
  authenticate:
    image: authenticate
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockeerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes: 
      - /data/authentica
    networks: 
      - "my-network"
networks:
  my-network:
```

It hasn't any different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service name and the connection string is different, you should use the exact service name or container name that is defined in docker-compose.

Change the connection string to

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/my_app?useSSL=false
```

update:

If the connection string does not resolve the issue, then there might be two possible reason

- application try to connect before the DB container is ready to accept connection
- [Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345377/unable-to-create-requested-service-org-hibernate-engine-jdbc-env-spi-jdbcenviro/36352826)

As in such cases `depends_on:` will not solve your problem, DB container takes some time to accept the connection. You can do something with [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or handle retry logic on the application side.

Comment: i think it's not my problem. I checked it but it hasn't anny problem