# I am using java 16.1 but I face this problem, Spring boot error showing while run the code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create requested service \[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345377/unable-to-create-requested-service-org-hibernate-engine-jdbc-env-spi-jdbcenviro)